# Spring bean field thread safety

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, concurrency, spring-bean

I have created a spring library in which there is a scheduler that fetches the configurations from config-server and injects it into fields of a bean.
Refer diagram below:

[image]

The problem is, under heavy load, there might occur thread concurrency issue. How should I prevent that?

Some code:

This is how a user will give a config key

```kotlin
    @AutoConfig("user")
data class ConfigurationWithPrefix (

    @ConfigValue("role")
    val role: String = ""
)

@AutoConfig
data class ConfigurationWithoutPrefix (

    @ConfigValue("user.role")
    val role: String = ""
)
```

**`@AutoConfig` annotation will make this class a bean.**
Then I fetch the bean by `@AutoConfig` annotation and inserts the value in the `@ConfigValue` key.

```kotlin
field.set(
          bean,
          valueFromConfig
 )
```

**This process has occurred on a different thread, so while inserting field value if my code tried to access the field concurrency issue will be there, how to prevent it?**

Comment: The key question is if the object is modified after it is created. If it is not, then normally Spring provides a happens before relation between construction and usage. If the object is modified after it is created, you need to deal with some form of synchronization (e.g. a volatile). But I would think twice about following this road.

Comment: The Object is created by Spring and modified later by the scheduler, any other option than Volatile?

Comment: Volatile in itself is a good solution. I don't see why you want to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to cache read/write with multiple threads, for this kind of problem AtomicReference works better that has semantics similar to volatile without synchronization.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

Bean definitions can be converted to:

```
data class ConfigurationWithPrefix (

    @ConfigValue("role")
    val role: AtomicReference<String> = AtomicReference("")
)

@AutoConfig
data class ConfigurationWithoutPrefix (

    @ConfigValue("user.role")
    val role: AtomicReference<String> = AtomicReference("")
)
```

Comment: AtomicReference with a get/set has same semantics as volatile.

Comment: Not sure (even if it works) if it's a good Idea to add such a huge restriction on users.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid point. We can create some extension function to get value to access it easily. You can try with producer - consumer pattern with a Reentrant lock, provided Bean should be singleton so that all threads communicates through read and write lock.